# Spring security keeps returning 401 Unauthorized code despite correct credentials provided

Tags: java, spring-security

After configuring a custom user details service that uses an embedded H2 database to retrieve user credentials, I keep receiving 401 Unauthorized errors when completing a post command even though the username and password are available. I don't know if this makes any difference, but the console still prints out the generated security password (although the auto generated credentials return the same 401 error). Please take a look at my code below and let me know any suggestions or fixes available.

User model...

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String username, password, role;

    public ApplicationUser(String username, String role, String password) {
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        this.role=role;
    }

    public ApplicationUser() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplicationUser{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User repository class...

```
@Repository
public class AppUserRepository {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    static class ApplicationUserRowMapper implements RowMapper<ApplicationUser> {
        @Override
        public ApplicationUser mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            ApplicationUser applicationUser = new ApplicationUser();
            applicationUser.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            applicationUser.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            applicationUser.setRole(rs.getString("userrole"));
            return applicationUser;
        }
    }

    public List<ApplicationUser> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select u.username, u.password, ur.userrole from ApplicationUsers u, ApplicationUsers_Role ur where u.username = ur.username",
                new ApplicationUserRowMapper());
    }

    public ApplicationUser findByUsername(String username) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select u.username, u.password, ur.userrole from ApplicationUsers u, ApplicationUsers_Role ur where u.username = ? and u.username = ur.username",
                new Object[] {username}, new ApplicationUserRowMapper());
    }
}
```

Security config class...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "security_package")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");
    }
}
```

Custom authentication provider...

```
@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    AppUserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        ApplicationUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(name);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed.");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuthorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Main app class...

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={
        HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableScheduling
@Slf4j
public class AwsorchestratorApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
  @Override
  public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    if (arg0.length > 0 && arg0[0].equals("exitcode")) {
      throw new ExitException();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if ( System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") == null )
    {
      System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active","local");
    }
    new SpringApplication(AwsorchestratorApplication.class).run(args);
  }

  class ExitException extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
      return 10;
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE ONE::...

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        ApplicationUser user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found.");
        }

        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), Collections.singletonList(grantedAuthority));
    }
}
```

Comment: I should note that the password stored in the h2 db is encrypted using BCrypt. Also I manually tested the repository methods to ensure they return the user and that worked as well.

Comment: As per the code details are fetched with `AppUserRepository` . What is the logic within `CustomUserDetailsService `?

Comment: Please see UPDATE ONE. Thanks @R.G

Comment: I just noticed you are not comparing the passwords on authentication. Ignore my previous comment pls

Comment: could you please confirm if within `CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` the user returned from DB is not null ?

Comment: I tested the method and was able to successfully return the user.

Comment: Could you please set `logging.level.org.springframework.security= debug ` and check what is going wrong

Comment: Thank you! That helped me understand where the security config went wrong. Please see my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to correct this issue by removing my custom authentication class (although I don't think this was actually part of the problem), and editing my web security config to match the below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = package_location)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService detailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //the password encoder here is only to support a mix of encoding - that change can be removed
        auth.userDetailsService(detailsService).passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/awsorchestrator/**")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

The important part that directly correlated to my problem was the passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()) portion. I also had to change the password stored in the database to be prefixed with {bcrypt} and now I am able to login with no issues.

Thanks R.G for the tips.

Comment: Could you please explain why the passwords in db have to be prefixed with {bcrypt} ?

Comment: It tells security that is a BCrypt encoded password since we don't specify this in the password encoder config.

Comment: the ".and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()" solved my problem